# Process to Create Bootable IMG Backup of Windows Partition Via LiveUSB

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, disk-image

Is it possible to create a bootable `img` of my Windows10 partition via the gnome-disk utility?

Or rather, what is the best / recommended way for creating a bootable image of Windows partition via an Ubuntu 20.04 LiveUSB session?

Can a bootable img of a Windows partition be created from within Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 without the need of a LiveUSB session?

My goal is to create a bootable image of my Windows 10 partition,so that I can convert it .vdi format and use it with Vbox6.1 inside Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though it's possible to [make a Windows 10 VM](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-setup-windows-10-virtual-machine-linux) running on Linux, the process requires you start with a generic Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft, VirtualBox or other installation media. After that, you can try to customize the Windows 10 on VM to more closely resemble your current Windows OS.

It [*was* possible to make a Windows-to-Go](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview) copy of the OS, **but,** "Windows To Go is removed in Windows 10, version 2004 and later operating systems. The feature does not support feature updates and therefore does not enable you to stay current. It also requires a specific type of USB that is no longer supported by many OEMs."